# Fsolve with variables from other arrays

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-functions

I have the following function:

```
function F = F(x,L,Kc1,Kc2,Kc3,Kc4)
F=[(2*L*x(1)^2)/Kc1 + L*x(1)*x(2)/Kc3 + x(1)+ (x(1)*Kc4/L)^0.5 - (2*(0.235)); (2*L*(x(2)^2))/Kc2 + x(2)+ L*x(1)*x(2)/Kc3 -2*(0.765)];
end
```

Here, `L,Kc1,Kc2,Kc3 and Kc4` are arrays which already have 99 numerical values stored in them. Thus, I need to solve for `x(1) and x(2)` 99 times and store them in the arrays O2 and N2. For this, the code is:

```
x0=[-5 -5];
O2=zeros(1,99);
N2=zeros(1,99);
for i=1:1:99
    x=fsolve(@(x)F(x,L(i),Kc1(i),Kc2(i),Kc3(i),Kc4(i)),x0);
    O2(i)=x(1);
    N2(i)=x(2);
end
```

Ideally, i should have gotten the arrays O2 and N2 by solving these equations. However, when I run my program, I get the following error:

```
??? Error using ==> vertcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.

Error in ==> F at 2
F=[(2*L*(x(1)^2))/Kc1 + L*x(1)*x(2)/Kc3 + x(1)+ (x(1)*Kc4/L)^0.5 - (2*(0.235)); (2*L*(x(2)^2))/Kc2 +
x(2)+ L*x(1)*x(2)/Kc3 -2*(0.765)];

Error in ==> @(x)F(x,L(i),Kc1(i),Kc2(i),Kc3(i),Kc4(i))


Error in ==> fsolve at 254
            fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});

Error in ==> Air_equilibriuw at 76
   x=fsolve(@(x)F(x,L(i),Kc1(i),Kc2(i),Kc3(i),Kc4(i)),x0);

Caused by:
    Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. FSOLVE cannot continue.
```

Does anyone know what's wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I count 6 inputs to F(), but you are passing 7 inputs including the additional x0. Check the parentheses.

Comment: I changed the parentheses. I am still getting an error, but a new one. I have edited the comment. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check the division and multiplication by L in the concatenated expression. Use `dbstop if error`, then run your code. When done `dbclear if error`.

Comment: I've found out the mistake. There should have been a comma between the 2 functions used in F, instead of a semicolon. F=[(2*L*x(1)^2)/Kc1 + L*x(1)*x(2)/Kc3 + x(1)+ (x(1)*Kc4/L)^0.5 - (2*(0.235)), (2*L*(x(2)^2))/Kc2 + x(2)+ L*x(1)*x(2)/Kc3 -2*(0.765)];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
function F = F(x,L,Kc1,Kc2,Kc3,Kc4)
    F=[(2*L*x(1)^2)/Kc1 + L*x(1)*x(2)/Kc3 + x(1)+ (x(1)*Kc4/L)^0.5 - (2*(0.235)); (2*L*(x(2)^2))/Kc2 + x(2)+ L*x(1)*x(2)/Kc3 -2*(0.765)];
end
```

to

```
function F = F(x,L,Kc1,Kc2,Kc3,Kc4)
    F=[(2*L*x(1)^2)/Kc1 + L*x(1)*x(2)/Kc3 + x(1)+ (x(1)*Kc4/L)^0.5 - (2*(0.235)), (2*L*(x(2)^2))/Kc2 + x(2)+ L*x(1)*x(2)/Kc3 -2*(0.765)];
end
```

Now F will be of size `[2 x 1]` instead of `[1 x 2]`, and your `vertcat` error will go away.